# Subresource Integrity Protection in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, subresource-integrity

I have getting subresource integrity error while scanning my website on https://observatory.mozilla.org/

I tried to use wp-sri plugin but its conflicting with other plugin, is there any other way to fix it.

Error test score screenshot:

[image]